# How can I write spring data query with IN statement?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to get Entity1's by entity2's ids

There is params for query -  List numbers - ids of entity2
.
And two entities with @OneToMany bound

```
@Entity
class Entity1 {
private Integer id;

private Entity2 entity2;

---------
@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
@Column
public Entity2 getEntity2(){
return entity2;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Entity2{

private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(FetchType.LAZY)
private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

i have working code

```
@Repository
public interface Entity1Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT c" +
            " FROM  Entity1 c" +
            " inner JOIN  c.entity2 a" +
            "  WHERE  a.id IN(?1)")
    Set<Entity1> findByEntity2Ids(List<Integer> pEntity2_Ids);
}
```

i want beautify query by using Spring Data

and write something like

```
Set<Entity1> findAllByEntity2In(List<Integer> pChannels);
```

but it doesnt work now

I catch an Enxception :

\Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [2] did not match expected type [com.test.Entity2 (n/a)]

Who knows how to solve?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

I found out the query for Spring Data :

```
  @Repository
    public interface Entity1Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Integer> {
 
    Set<Enity1> findByEntity2In(List<Integer> pEntities2Ids);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the query.
It should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT c" +
            " FROM  Entity1 c" +
            " inner JOIN  c.entity2 a" +
            "  WHERE  a.id IN ?1")
```

For a better readable query, you could choose to use a named parameter instead of a positional one. Said so, your query could be like this:

```
@Query("SELECT c" +
            " FROM  Entity1 c" +
            " inner JOIN  c.entity2 a" +
            "  WHERE  a.id IN :ids")
    Set<Entity1> findByEntity2Ids(@Param("ids") List<Integer> pEntity2_Ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do search by List or set of Entity2 like

```
Set<Entity1> findByEntity2In(Set<Entity2> entity2);
```

For finding by Entity2 Id, you need to write Query like

```
@Query("SELECT ent1 FROM  Entity1 ent1 INNER JOIN  c.entity2 ent2 WHERE  ent2.id IN :ids")
Set<Entity1> findByEntity2Ids(@Param("ids") List<Integer> pEntity2_Ids);
```